# AWS S3: change storage class without replicating the object

Tags: amazon-s3, replication

My bucket has a replication rule to backup the object into another region/bucket.

Now I want to change the storage class in the source object (standard -> infrequent access), but it seems this change, applied through CopyObjectRequest API (java client), is triggering the replication. This is unfortunate because cross-region replication has a cost.

So at the moment the "journey" is the following:

1. object is stored in standard class, source bucket
2. I change the storage class to IA
3. object gets replicated into another region (standard class)
4. after 1 day it's moved to glacier.

As you can see this is a total waste of money, because the replication will end up moving the very same object into glacier again.

How can I avoid this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Use a lifecycle policy in the source bucket to convert the current object version to the desired storage class.  This should migrate the current object without changing its version-id, and should not trigger a replication event.

Otherwise, you'd need to create objects with the desired storage class from the beginning.  There isn't a way for a user action to change an object's storage class without creating a new object version, so the seemingly redundant replication event can't otherwise be avoided -- because you are creating a new object version.

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow both advice: create new objects with desired storage class, and add a lifecycle rule for existing objects. As for existing objects, unfortunately  I can't use a prefix to select the objects I need to change, but could add a tag and then apply the rule to that tag.

Comment: hmm I am afraid tagging would arise the same issue. Also I can't use regex to narrow down the objects I am interested in because this is not supported. Sometimes it seems AWS does its best to prevent you from lowering the bill :) I reckon only solution left is to stop replication, change storage class, restore replication, and finally force replication on objects that were created in the meanwhile.

Comment: I would expect tagging changes not to cause re-replication.

Comment: you are right...but there is another problem now. if done through a lifecycle rule, it takes 30 days to move to One Zone-Infrequent Access. So I'd have to wait for 1 month to test it, and another month to see the result in production. F*** them, I'll disable/enable replication, it's much easier....